# Apps with satanic logos

Tags: halal-haram

السلام علیکم

I want to ask that logos of some apps for example google chrome has 666 in its logo and google play store has sigil of lucifer being a Muslim should I be concerned about it. Or is it halal to use such apps

Jazak Allah Khair

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63627/logos-that-resembles-with-evil-logos

Comment: Islam doesn't encourage the belief in numerology. Thus numeric symbols like 786 or 666 have no standing for a muslim.